# How to solve the problem of "ValueError: expected square matrix"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, syntax-error

I will solve a linear equation Ax = b by using LU factorization. When I used this code for smaller matrices, the code worked great, but when I entered my large matrix, it did not work. Instead, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    LU = linalg.lu_factor(A) 
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_lu.py", line 76, in lu_factor
    raise ValueError('expected square matrix')
ValueError: expected square matrix
```

Here you can se my code:

```
import pprint
import scipy
import math

#import linalg package of the SciPy module for the LU decomp 
import scipy.linalg as linalg

#import NumPy 
import numpy as np 

#define A same as before 
A = np.array([[math.sin(45), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [-(math.sin(45)), 0, -1, 1, math.sin(45), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [0, 0, 0, 0, -(math.sin(45)), 0, 1, 0, math.sin(45), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(math.sin(45)), 0, -1, 0, math.sin(45), 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, math.sin(45), 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(math.sin(45)), 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(math.sin(45)), -1]])  

#define B 
B = np.array([0, 0, 10, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0])  

#call the lu_factor function 
LU = linalg.lu_factor(A) 


#solve given LU and B 
x = linalg.lu_solve(LU, B) 

print ("Solutions:\n",x)

#now we want to see how A has been factorized, P is the so called Permutation matrix 
P, L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(A)

print ("P:") 
pprint.pprint(P)

print ("L:") 
pprint.pprint(L)

print ("U:")
pprint.pprint(U)
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: The solution is to use a square matrix, as the error said. You have `A`, which is a 10 x 17 matrix, and that is not square.

Comment: `A` is of shape `(10, 17)` which is not a square matrix

Answer (score 0):

Use [this solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html) for not square matrix:

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A, b, damp=0.0, atol=1e-08, btol=1e-08, conlim=100000000.0, iter_lim=None, show=False, calc_var=False, x0=None)
```

Find the least-squares solution to a large, sparse, linear system of equations.

The function solves Ax = b or min ||Ax - b||^2 or min ||Ax - b||^2 + d^2 ||x||^2.

The matrix A may be square or rectangular (over-determined or under-determined), and may have any rank.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering me. How do I use this code in my code? I have tried but do not understand... :)